# Handling UIView geometry programmatically for iOS 6 and 7 apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have several apps that were developed for iOS 6 and for the time being need to work in both 6 and 7 (until we drop 6 at some point in the future). All views are generated programmatically. For a `UIViewController` nested inside `UINavigationController`, it is fairly trivial to fix the geometry of underlying views by adding this to `viewDidLoad`

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]){
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Yet when I have a "naked" `viewController` - presented directly without a navigation bar - I have to explicitly offset each view (at least those with hardcoded `frame.origin.y` values) by the height of the status bar, which seems a lot less efficient. Are there any more graceful ways to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Autolayouts you should take a look at the properties *`topLayoutGuide`* and *`bottomLayoutGuide`* of `UIViewController` (introduced with iOS7).
They also handle the case, if your view controller is not nested in a container view controller (such as a navigation controller)

[TopLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/topLayoutGuide)

[BottomLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/bottomLayoutGuide)